# Effective potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, renormalization

Given that after renormalization, we can write:

$$\Im\left(\mathcal{M} \right) = \Im\left(-\frac{-\lambda^2}{32 \pi^2} \int_{0}^{1} dx \ln(m^2 + p^2x(1-x)) \right)$$

The $(m^2 + p^2x(1-x))$ needs to be negative so we have an imaginary part, thus:

$$m^2 + p^2x(1-x) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow x = -\frac{1}{2}\left( 1 \pm \sqrt{1 + \frac{4m^2}{p^2}}\right)$$

We also know that: $\Im \left( \ln\left(- X \pm i \epsilon \right) \right)$, $X > 0$ thus:

$$\mathcal{M} =-\frac{\lambda^2}{32 \pi^2} \int_{1-\beta}^{1 + \beta} dx (-\pi) = \frac{\lambda^2}{16 \pi} \sqrt{1 + \frac{4m^2}{p^2}} $$

Knowing that: $$\mathcal{M} = -\frac{\lambda^2}{2} V(p^2) \longrightarrow V(p^2) = -\frac{1}{8 \pi} \sqrt{1 + \frac{4m^2}{p^2}}$$

The effective potential is the Fourier transform of $V(p^2)$:

$$V(r) = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2 \pi)^3} e^{i p \cdot r} V(p^2)$$

but, I don't know how to integrate this expression analytical. How do I do this?

If we are in non-relativistic limit, what changes? And if $r \gg 1/m$?

P.S:

$\beta = \frac{4m^2}{p^2}$

Comment: In spherical coordinates.

Comment: Yeah, I know that... But the integral in dp seems impossible, to do analytically, due to the terms of the exponential and of V(p). Am I doing something wrong in the calculation of V(p)?

Comment: check in Gradshtein & Ryzhik, and also the tablesfor Laplace transform (e.g., in Abramowitz & Stegun).